# Text size and style differs in Qt desktop and embedded applications

Tags: qt, user-interface, fonts, styles, embedded

I'm developing GUI embedded application for lpc3250 ARM board using QtCreator and QtEmbedded-4.8.2-arm cross toolchain built with NXP gcc-4.3.2-glibc-2.7 on Kubuntu 12.10. The problem is in difference between text size and text style in desktop and embedded applications. Text (labels, table headers etc) in embedded app GUI is distinctly smaller and formatting is broken (e.g. no bold text). Seems like something is wrong with fonts, but they are installed to the same dir ( /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.2-arm/lib/fonts ) both on desktop and embedded device, and I don't understand what may be wrong with them.

Could anybody advise, what's wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `export QT_QWS_FONTDIR=*<font path>*` on the ARM.

Comment: Also, some fonts may not display on the lpc3250 as you need external libraries to display *True Type* and other fonts.  The only ones you may be able to display are the fixed `qfp` and `qfp2` fonts.  The *True Type* fonts take a lot of memory and CPU; for embedded applications, they may not be installed by default.

Comment: Tried to set QT_QWS_FONTDIR - nothing happens.

Tried to create needed QPF fonts using makeqpf tool (on device) - nothing too.

Comment: Run `strace` and see what files it is using with `open()`.  Your `configure` option give the font rendering engines to use.  Have you configured with *freetype*?  See: [Qt embedded font docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-fonts.html).

Comment: Rebuilt Qt Embedded with freetype support (-qt-freetype option) and get desired result. Also it was needed to play with QWS_DISPLAY variable (mmWidth and mmHeight options), the value QWS_DISPLAY=LinuxFB:mmWidth=250:mmHeight=150 seems to be the best solution for my 7 inch touchscreen (previous value QWS_DISPLAY=LinuxFB:mmWidth=800:mmHeight=480 results in too small font size with freetype-supported Qt lib).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building Qt Embedded with freetype support solved the problem

Comment: set the lable font size or any object font size
in css. it becomes true.